# e(fx)clipse CSS error: Interface expected

Tags: css, eclipse, javafx, efxclipse

I have a following problem with e(fx)clipse:

Whenever I try to write some CSS code using e(fx)clipse CSS Editor I keep getting a syntax error:

```
Syntax error on token ".", interface expected
```

when using dot with class selectors like in this example:

```
.root{
    -fx-font-size: 16pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Courier New";
    -fx-base: rgb(132, 145, 47);
    -fx-background: rgb(225, 228, 203);
}
```

When I don't use the "." the error looks like this:

```
Syntax error on token "root", interface expected before this token
```

Other features of e(fx)clipse, even CSS autocompletion, work ok. I have no idea what's going on, so any help would be appreciated.

My setup is:

  Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 4.4.2.20150219-0708

  e(fx)clipse - IDE 1.2.0.201501301049

  Java 1.8.0_45-b14

  Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: These look like the errors you would get from the Java compiler if it was  trying to interpret this as Java.  What file extension are you using for this file?

Comment: @greg-449 The file is in .css format. I've discovered, that the problem is related to Java projects created with the e(fx)clipse tool in this way: New -> Other -> JavaFX Project. When I edit CSS files in e.g. Web Projects, everything works fine, even with the e(fx)clipse CSS editor. It's probably some kind of Content Type error, but I'm just guessing.